# Create a custom template for moodle - version 2.8.3

Tags: css, moodle

Currently I've started working in moodle. But I have some confusion, how do I create a custom theme.

I designed a new template using html & Css.  But I don't know how to migrate with moodle.  I tried something in google. But I cant find a good solution.

Please can anyone provide me details to do this in moodle.

My problem is that I don't know how to add my custom HTML/JS with a custom theme setting.

Moodle version is 2.8.3.

Thank you, if you can provide me with any guidelines and references for solving this problem.

Comment: Use this link to understand how you can create theme in Moodle.https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Creating_a_theme

Comment: Please provide some sort of code.. you are trying to do